# SAXNotRecognizedException in Play for Scala 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, playframework-2.6

I'm migrating from Play 2.5 to 2.6, the application compiles with no issues, but when I start Play I get the exception below. The error mentions `AkkaHttpServer` - the new default HTTP server in Play 2.6. I tried adding to `application.conf` the Akka HTTP server standard configuration taken from Play's website but I still get the same error.

Looking at the [SAX Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException.html) it says that there's a property not recognized by the parser. Any ideas how to fix this?

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected
>   exception[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:190)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>           at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:202)
>           at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:117)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$25.onPush(Ops.scala:1194)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:585)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:469)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**: null
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:177)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>           at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:202)
>           at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:117)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$25.onPush(Ops.scala:1194)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:585)
>           at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:469)
>   **Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException**:
>   http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(AbstractSAXParser.java:1508)
>           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:145)
>           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.(SAXParserImpl.java:128)
>           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:112)
>           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:140)
>           at play.api.Play$.(Play.scala:58)
>           at play.api.Play$.(Play.scala)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:177)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>           at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:202)

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of trial an error, I discovered that changing the version of `commons-dbcp` from 1.2 to 1.4 fixed the problem. The error message doesn't seem to point to the resolution.